# I have a syntax Error in My OCR Program in resize the image

Tags: c#, ocr

Hello every body i have an error in my code and i try to fixed it but i cant
at first i make a function prepare_ORCEngine

```
void prepare_ORCEngine(string path)
    {
        im = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);
        pbProduct.Image =  Resize_IMG(path);
        ocrs = new Ocr();
        ocrs.SetBitmap(im);

    }
```

i get error in `Resize_IMG(path)` so that i make the function `Resize_IMG`

```
private Image Resize_IMG(string path)
        {

        }
```

but i have an error in the function `Resize_IMG`

```
Error   4   'Epic.ocr.Resize_IMG(string)': not all code paths return a value
```

so what should i do to fixing it.

Comment: What is your implementation of Resize_IMG? It must return a Image.

Comment: `private Image Resize_IMG(string path)` method does not return any value ..why you are assigning to `pbProduct.Image` ?

Comment: `pbProduct.Image` this is ImageBox and this `private Image Resize_IMG(string path)` function to resize the image put i have no idea to did it

Comment: You will see that error until you put something in your function that returns an Image.